# Why am I seeing multiple months in the results when I am joining with dim_date

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is my simple Postgresql Query

```
SELECT dd.year_actual as yr, sum("Ordered_Amount") from channel_sales cs
JOIN dim_date dd ON cs."date" = dd.date_actual
GROUP BY
dd.year_actual,
cs."Ordered_Amount"
```

Here is the result below. What I was expecting was a single line result with the year and total amount, but instead it is breaking it down into multiple rows of 2018. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
2018    2226
2018    357
2018    616
2018    1074
2018    1422
2018    3080
2018    2106
2018    924
2018    176
2018    580
2018    1587
2018    14350
2018    306
2018    2516
2018    1482
2018    2880
2018    8400
2018    5200
2018    16758
2018    781
2018    135
2018    4056
2018    150
2018    500
2018    2338
2018    3850
2018    1432
2018    1396
2018    1230
2018    274
2018    1494
2018    1068
2018    878
2018    1441
2018    1832
2018    3042
2018    4180
2018    2327
2018    206
2018    426
2018    2090
2018    1003
2018    62499
2018    900
2018    2274
2018    399
2018    1980
2018    278
2018    736
2018    24070
2018    561
2018    648
2018    1256
2018    120
2018    21912
2018    1639
2018    4452
2018    1008
2018    96577
2018    3240
2018    1386
2018    388
2018    260
2018    1080
2018    5525
2018    2672
2018    24674
2018    4392
2018    948
2018    801
2018    658
2018    1908
2018    692
2018    498
2018    630
2018    8999
2018    4056
2018    2990
2018    1745
2018    1280
2018    126
2018    988
2018    422
2018    936
```

Is it how I am making the join, or is it because I am using group by clause in the wrong way. I cannot figure out for the life of it.

Comment: Besause you are not grouping by only year.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are not grouping by only year. You are also grouping by ordered_amount which you also sum(). Thus you are effectively summing by year and common ordered_amounts. If say in 2018, there are 4 ordered_amounts of 100 that would show as 2018, 400. And this would be repeated per ordered_amount. ie:

```
2018,100
2018,100
2018,100
2018,100
2018,200
2018,300
2018,300
```

would be:

```
2018,400
2018,200
2018,600
```

Write it as:

```
SELECT dd.year_actual as yr, sum("Ordered_Amount") 
from channel_sales cs
  JOIN dim_date dd ON cs."date" = dd.date_actual
GROUP BY 
dd.year_actual
```

Also note that if this is not a 1-to-many or 1-to-1 relation, then sum results would be wrong. To prevent that, you may first do the sum and then join. Depending on table structures and which data is coming from where, a join may not even be needed.

Comment: That was simple...... Thank you so much for the quick response.